# Duplicate PVs error in GParted when attempting to delete RAID1 setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, raid, gparted

**Problem**
When attempting to delete the remnants of my RAID1 setup I'm getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
WARNING: Use multipath or vgimportclone to resolve duplicate PVs
```

**Background:**
I'm *very* new to Linux, and am currently on a journey to setup an Ubuntu server with a 1TB maindisk supported by 2x 2TB data disks in a RAID1 array. The RAID1 array is configured via the motherboard and was working as expected, however I made the mistake of attempting to install Ubuntu to the RAID1 array.

Once I realized how foolish that was I disconnected the RAID drives and connected a 1TB maindisk, to which I installed Ubuntu. That went ok (nVidia drivers were a hurdle to overcome.)

With that installed I then reconnected my RAID1 array only to find that my previous installation Ubuntu attempts were still on there, and now the system was mounting them when I booted up rather than mounting my new install on my maindisk.

My thinking at this point was:

1. Reset the machine
2. Remove the hardware RAID1 setup on boot
3. Boot GParted from CD
4. Delete the data left over from the RAID1 partitions
5. Reboot the machine
6. Recreate the RAID1 hardware setup
7. Boot GParted from CD
8. Format the RAID1 partition in ext4
9. Reboot machine back into Ubuntu
10. Mount the new RAID1 partition

I got to step 4 - at this point GParted is telling me that there are 'duplicate PVs' on the system. I've attempted to Google this problem and also search stack exchange, but I think my naivety with Linux is blocking me from seeing the answer.

My assumption is that the PV is some sort of drive controller and I've completed botched up the state of the drives, meaning that when GParted runs this command it gets confused:

```
lvm pvremove /dev/sdb5
```

If anyone could help me figure this out I'd be in their debt, especially if I can get pointers to resources for all these new acronyms I'm coming across (what is PV for example.)

Thanks!

Comment: Linux on software RAID 1 or on true hardware RAID 1 should work just fine.  Your problem was using the motherboard's sort-of-maybe fake hardware RAID 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone posted on another forum - turns out the `wipefs` command was what I needed. I ran the following from GParted and now I'm back in business:

```
sudo wipefs -a /dev/sda
sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdb
```

This wiped the two drives back to a completely unallocated state, and now I've reset up the RAID1 array, created a new partition, and formatted it with ext4.